# How to update a value to a appropriate place if the dictionary has single key multiple values?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key, multiple-value

I have a CSV file with header task;a1_data;a2_data;a3_data. I have considered task as key and rest of the columns as values. a1,a2,a3 are variables here. When the input value is a1 it should update the column 'a1_data', when its is a2 it should update the column 'a2_data' and when the values is equal to a3 it should update column 'a3_data'.

```
with open(data_file, 'r', newline="\n") as data_List:
    for row in data_List:
        row = str(row).strip("\r\n ")
        x = row.split(";")
        index_data[x[0]] = x[1:]
```

Till here i was able to do it but confused on updating of the column. can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Since the values are a list you can simply update the desired item. Assuming you have a key `k` and your input is "a1" so you want to update the first item ("a1_data") with a value `v`, you would do `index_data[k][0] = v`

Comment: I want to do this in a generic method. Is there any solution to do this in a generic way? instead of manually assigning.. if there can you please help me in this.